# How to keep vertical align text in middle independently of font-family and font-size?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a vertical centralized text.

**But the problem is**: When I increase the `font-size`, different browsers render a different font-family (font stack) and its not keep middle alignment.

http://jsfiddle.net/rpNnh/1/

Thanks!

Comment: Your demo is about switching font-family while you say your issue is about font-size... (And I think the font-family part is not doable. It sounds like having the same width for the same text in the same font-size, but with differents fonts...) [different demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rpNnh/5/).

Answer (score 1):

see the solution in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpNnh/12/)

In detail

Html code

```
<div>
<p>text+<br>sdffd</p>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<a href="#" class="switchFont">Switch Font</a>​
```

CSS

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table; //added
}
p{
    line-height: 20px; //changed
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell; //added
    vertical-align: middle; //added
}

p.times{
    font-family: "verdana"; //changed
}
```

​

Comment: verify compatibility in different browser if there are some restriction

Answer (score 0):

You can vertically align a text in middle by placing this CSS on the div:

```
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```